# Return different MIME types based on Accept header parameter on Amazon AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, http-accept-header

Could you explain how to setup Amazon AWS API Gateway to return different documents based on the request HTTP Accept header?

Two examples:

- curl --request GET 'http://api.sample.com/v1/hello' --header 'Accept: text/HTML'

  ```
  <html><body>Hello, World!</body></html>
  ```
- curl --request GET 'http://api.sample.com/v1/hello' --header 'Accept: application/JSON'

  ```
  {data:"Hello, World!"}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want API Gateway to act as a template rendering engine I don't think that will work but you could let your Lambda know which content-type the requester is looking for by passing the Accept header to your Lambda and let Lambda decide what to return.

You will need a mapping template(under Method Execution -> Integration Request -> Mapping Templates) for each Content-Type(data the requester is sending) you want to support.

A sample mapping template which takes the input from the request and transforms it into the JSON `event` so Lambda can work with it:

```
{
  "headers": {
    // maybe there is an easier way for Lambda to get this but I couldn't find it in the context object so I believe APIG needs to send it like this
    "Accept": "$input.params('Accept')"
  },
  "message": "$input.params('message')"
}
```

Then in your lambda you can check the Accept header and send back a response based on that:

```
module.exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var msg = event.message.toUpperCase()

    if(event.headers.Accept === 'text/html') {
      return context.succeed('<html><body><h1>Transformed Message: ' + msg + '</h1></body></html>');
    }
    // all other requests get JSON...
    context.succeed({transformedMessage: msg});
};
```

And the last step is back in API Gateway - under Method Execution -> Method RESPONSE -> Add Response. The Model can just be empty but set the Content-Type to `text/html`. This will tell API Gateway to let whatever you send back from Lambda pass through to any requests where Accept: text/html

EDIT: This answer assumed you are using Lambda as the backend but really the same idea could be applied to almost any backend service that you're using.

Comment: Ryan, is there anyway to simply passthrough the entire request header and body to the backend? bypassing Integration Request.